# Open one component instance at a time in Ember Octane

Tags: ember.js, ember-octane

Let's say we have component `answer` that has `isOpen` property. By default `isOpen` is `false` and when the user is clicking on the `answer` we are changing the `isOpen` to `true`.

We are showing the list of answers. How can we close the first `answer` when the user clicks on second `answer`?

I was thinking about creating a service `answersSync` with `globalIsOpen = false`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest keeping track of which answer is open in your parent component, the one that lists the answers. Then your parent template would look something like:

```
{{#each this.answers as |answer|}}
  <Answer
    @answer={{answer}}
    isOpen={{eq this.currentlyOpenAnswer answer}}
    {{on "click" (fn this.openAnswer answer)}}
  />
{{/each}}
```

(then have code in the parent component's js that keeps track of `currentlyOpenAnswer`, responding to the `openAnswer` action)

Comment: @spirito_libero - Did this work for you?